# How to get Previous date in PHP?

Tags: php

I have variable that get user selected check out date from the form. Like this `$chkoutdate=$_POST['chkod'];`

It store like `'2016-06-23'` format.
Give me a way to get the previous date of `**$chkoutdate**`

ex. I want to get `'2016-06-22'` as the result.

Please give a code in php .
Thank you
Dinusha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the below code:

```
<?php
    $chkoutdate = '2016-06-23';
    $PreviousDate =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime($chkoutdate.' - 1 day'));
    echo $PreviousDate;
?>
```

Output:
2016-06-22

Comment: Yes you can apply the above code by just replacing the hard coded date value by soft code i.e by post vale

Answer (score 4):

Try This

```
<?php
$date = isset($_GET['date']) ? $_GET['date'] : date('Y-m-d');
$prev_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date .' -1 day'));
echo $prev_date;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$previous_chkoutdate =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime($chkoutdate.' - 1 day'));
```

Result:

```
2016-06-22
```